# How to get Facebook video id from it's url?

Tags: php, regex, facebook, facebook-graph-api, preg-match

I have searched through lots of questions but I can't find the correct solution as Facebook changed it's URL strategies.
For example: if the video URL is

```
https://www.facebook.com/yourstartupsIndia/videos/977323192329199/
```

How can I get the video id from the url. ie : `977323192329199`

Comment: What is not working in your code?

Comment: @Toto , Can't get the video id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the regex `(\d+)/$`, `\d` mean any digit, and `/$` mean ending with `/`

```
preg_match("#(\d+)/$#", 'https://www.facebook.com/yourstartupsIndia/videos/977323192329199/', $vid);
echo $vid[1];
# 977323192329199
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-regex solutions, consider these:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d87f0e58fd730db3ba72cb8cd5dc4724836b3a4))

```
$url='https://www.facebook.com/yourstartupsIndia/videos/977323192329199/';

//string functions:
echo substr($url,strrpos(rtrim($url,'/'),'/')+1,-1);

echo "\n\n";

//array functions:
echo array_slice(explode('/',$url),-2,1)[0];
```

Output:

```
977323192329199

977323192329199
```